# convert a DURATION HH:MM:SS to seconds in bash

Tags: bash, time, duration

I would like to get a way to convert easily a duration (and not the time from 1970 etc etc) like 05:42:32 to the duration in seconds. Is there a easy and rapid way to do this in bash please ? 
I tried with "date" and %s etc but it always returns a time since 1970 and I only want a duration.

Thanks !

Answer (score 5):

Does `awk` count as bash?

```
$ echo "05:42:32" | awk -F':' '{print $1 * 60 * 60 + $2 * 60 + $3}'
20552
```

If you also need to parse durations without hours:

```bsh
awk -F':' '{if (NF == 2) {print $1 * 60 + $2} else {print $1 * 60 * 60 + $2 * 60 + $3}}'
```

Comment: And also, how to get it in a variable called for example "duration" rather than echo the result ?
Thank you !

Comment: You can assign the result of any command to a variable with `variable=$( command )`. So `duration=$( wherever_you_get_your_time_from | awk ... )`

Comment: Ok thank you. I did this but I had removed the echo by mistake.

Answer (score 3):

You can use IFS to split the time into hours, minutes and seconds.

```
#! /bin/bash

to_seconds () {
    IFS=: read h m s <<< "$1"
    echo $(( 10#$h * 3600 + 10#$m * 60 + 10#$s ))
}

duration=05:42:32
to_seconds $duration
```

Comment: What is `multiply` for?

Comment: @PavelAnossov: Ouch, thank you. Deleted. I was originally experimenting with taking the numbers from right, multiplying them by 1, 60 and 3600...

Comment: Also you used $duration instead of $1.

Comment: @PavelAnossov: Thanks again. Time for coffee, I guess.

Comment: You will get octal errors for values "08" and "09". You need to specify base 10: `$(( 10#$h * 3600 + 10#$m * 60 + 10#$s ))`

Answer (score 2):

Pavel's answer is almost the standard solution.

Just for fun, you could do it in this way `(sed + bc)` too:

```
kent$  echo "05:42:32"|sed 's/:/*60+/g;s/*60/&&/'|bc
20552
```